# overriding class methods in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an iOS app in Obj C. I have a third party static library that contains a class, let's call it `aclass.m`, and I have access to its source code.

I want to use `aclass.m` but want to override its methods ( without rebuilding the original library )  so that the original implementation in the library is totally ignored in my app.

How can I accomplish this if at all?

Comment: google ObjC method swizzling

Answer (score 2):

You can override class methods the same as instance methods.

Subclass the class you want to extend (method override) and implement the methods you want to override.

This is inheritance and (part of) polymorphism used in Object Oriented Programming.